# Invalid session when running multiple test (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, automation

When running one test after another the second one always fails with invalid session error. Ignore the code its not refactored yet. Could somebody help me understand the reason?i put breakpoint on first line in second test and it does reaches it but fails with the following :

```
invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Artjoms-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:84a:618d:34b2:408c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.6', java.version: '15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 86.0.4240.111, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff..., userDataDir: /var/folders/z6/46cwjtvx2fj...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51827}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: d39535e6570e233ffb589877403d2d7d
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.cookie-accept-all}





  @@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyCardsServiceTest extends WebDriverSettings {

    private MyCardsService myCardsService;
    private HomePageService homePageService;
    private LoginService loginService;
    private MyAccountService myAccountService;
    private CookieModal cookieModal;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        cookieModal =  CookieModal.cookieModalInstance(driver);
        homePageService = HomePageService.homePageServiceInstance(driver);
        loginService = LoginService.loginServiceInstance(driver);
        myCardsService = MyCardsService.myCardsServiceInstance(driver);
        myAccountService = MyAccountService.myAccountServiceInstance(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessfullyAddCard() {
        cookieModal.acceptCookies();
        homePageService.clickOnMyAccountTab();
        loginService.login(loginCorrectData());
        homePageService.openMyAccountPage();
        myAccountService.myAccountPage().clickOnMyCardsTab();
        myCardsService.addCard(cardData());
        Assert.assertEquals(cardLastFourDigits, myCardsService.getMyCards().cardIndicator.getText());
    }
```

Here is my settings :

```
public class WebDriverSettings {

public WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    loginToEnvironment();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

current dependencies :

```
    dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.5'
    compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '4.2.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}
```

Comment: What unit test framework do you use? And which version?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Junit 4.12

Comment: @AlexeyR. i have added dependencies list and tried with newer junit version but still same problem

Comment: I just reproduced the structure like yours (with junit 4.12) and it is everything working fine on my side. What I can suggest is to update your question with minimal reproducible example. Also put a breakpoint to `driver = new ChromeDriver();`, run in debug and make sure it is called for both the tests.